# How to jump to next middleware(error handling middleware) when error is encounted in express application get() function

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

How to jump using `next()`, or some other techniques to only jump to the next middleware(that is my 404 page)?

```
app.get('/events/*', function(req, res){                     // /events/blob
var text = req.originalUrl.slice(8, req.originalUrl.length); // text = "blob"
app.locals.queried_event  = obj[text];                      // obj["blob"],if obj["blob"] is present it's ok but if it's not then it throws error
res.render("events"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to your error handling middleware if you want to, but you can also just return the error here:

```
app.get('/events/*', function(req, res){                     // /events/blob
    var text = req.originalUrl.slice(8, req.originalUrl.length); // text = "blob"
    app.locals.queried_event  = obj[text];                      // obj["blob"],
    if (obj.blob) {
        res.render("events"); 
    } else {
        res.status(404).render("404page");
    }
});
```

If you want to go to your error middleware, you'd declare the `next` argument and call it:

```
app.get('/events/*', function(req, res, next) {                     // /events/blob
    var text = req.originalUrl.slice(8, req.originalUrl.length); // text = "blob"
    app.locals.queried_event  = obj[text];                      // obj["blob"],
    if (obj.blob) {
        res.render("events"); 
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Or, you can pass a specific error object and go directly to your error handling middleware with `next(err)` where you make some specific error object to pass.